# Core i3 3220 for gaming

Tags: cpu, multi-core, cpu-architecture, hyper-threading

Since the Core i3 3220 has Hyper-Threading, will games like Battlefield 3 see and use the CPU as a virtual "quad core" rather than just 2 physical cores, so that AI and other features in the game run more efficiently?

Comment: Windows will see it as having four processors.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. I edited your question, it sounded a bit like a shopping request, masking the real question. If you are unhappy with the changes, feel free to revert them or edit the question again.

Comment: thank you for the responses. and thanks for the edit. it even made more sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer: they will use the four "logical" cores.

A program typically scales to multiple cores by running multiple concurrent "threads". The underlying OS typically manages which threads run where (called "scheduling"). If the OS sees 4 cores (and with hyper-threading, it will) - then four threads will run in parallel.

The game may have a variable number of threads, by asking the OS about the available number of cores. If this is the case, the game will most likely see four cores.